# Android: sort spinner entries (feeded via XML string-array)

Tags: android, sorting

I'm pretty new to Android so forgive me if I might not use the correct "terminology".

I've been looking at spinners and found out that there are two ways to add the entries:

1. in the .java file of my activity, using StringAdapters and so on
2. in the xml, using the "android:entries" attribute and a string-array defined in the *strings.xml* file

I tried the first option and was able to sort the Spinner options (I retrieved the string-array, put it into an ArrayList and then used Collections.sort... might not be the simplest solution), but **I would be rather interested in using the second option**, because since I already defined all my strings, it seems like it's going to make my code lighter... plus, I'd like to know if there's a way of oding what I'm trying to do...
I now have in *strings.xml* something like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="competition_backstroke100">Backstroke 100</string>
    <string name="competition_butterfly50">Butterfly 50</string>
    <string name="competition_butterfly100">Butterfly 100</string>

    <string-array name="competitions">
    <item>@string/competition_butterfly100</item>
    <item>@string/competition_backstroke100</item>
    <item>@string/competition_butterfly50</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

and put `android:entries="@array/competitions"` in my xml spinner definition

Now **my question**: the entries are added in the same order as they appear in the *competitions* definition. I understand that I could just sort them manually, but this wouldn't work in case my app runs in a different language (the order would stay the same, I guess). **Is there any way to sort my strings directly in the xml?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define different versions of the `<string-array>` resource as needed to affect the sort order, for translations that need a new sort order. IOW, if you translate `<string>` resources, you "translate" the `<string-array>` sort order as well.

Comment: so you mean in my italian file: values-it\strings.xml, I need to redefine the <string-array> with the same name? Oh this seems like quite some overhead... what if I add a new String in English and forget to add it to the Italian version? Will it be missing or is it going to be placed at the end?

Comment: @PLB: "so you mean in my italian file: values-it\strings.xml, I need to redefine the <string-array> with the same name?" -- yes, but only if the sort order is different. The longer the list, the more likely is that the sort order will change with the translations. "Oh this seems like quite some overhead" -- yes. Middle ground would be to *not* use `android:entries`, load the `<string-array>` yourself (`getResources().getStringArray()` or `getResources().getTextArray()`), sort it in Java, and use that with an `ArrayAdapter`.